# Returning multiple lists data inside an object in ASP dotnet Core API

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-core, controller, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this consignment Entity Model.

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
public bool? Deleted { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }
public string Services { get; set; }
public string CustomerReference { get; set; }
public string ConsignmentNote { get; set; }
public int? TotalPieces { get; set; }
...
public virtual ICollection<ConsignmentDocument> ConsignmentDocument { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ConsignmentLine> ConsignmentLine { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Legging> Legging { get; set; }
```

Now the problem that I am facing while fetching a consignment is that I am not getting any data of ConsignmentLine, Legging, ConsignmentDocument in the response body . I was testing it with only ConsignmentLine first in my Consignments Controller. This is my GetConsignment() controller method.

```
// GET: api/Consignments
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Consignment>> GetConsignment(Guid id)
    {
        var consignment = await _context.Consignment.where(c =>c.Id == id)
            .Include(conline => conline.ConsignmentLine)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        return consignment;
    }
```

My ConsignmentLine.cs is this :

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal? Length { get; set; }
    public decimal? Width { get; set; }
    public decimal? Height { get; set; }
    public decimal? Volume { get; set; }
    public int? Pieces { get; set; }
    public decimal? Weigth { get; set; }
    public bool? DangerousGoods { get; set; }
    public string DgClass { get; set; }
    public string UnNumber { get; set; }
    public Guid? ConsignmentId { get; set; }
    public Guid? ItemId { get; set; }
    public Guid? CommodityId { get; set; }
    public bool? Deleted { get; set; }
```

My Legging.cs is this:

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    public decimal? Cost { get; set; }
    public string LegType { get; set; }
    public string FromLeg { get; set; }
    public string ToLeg { get; set; }
    public Guid? CarrierAccount { get; set; }
    public Guid? ConsignmentId { get; set; }
    public bool? Deleted { get; set; }
```

I am testing it from postman and it is returning Json Exception. What should be expression then?

Comment: can you suggest any alternatives?

Comment: As said in an answer: you don't even need the `Where`.

Comment: but FirstOrDefault() returns an  error!

Comment: There is no `FirstOrDefault` in your code and just telling that it "returns an error" is meaningless. Also, you really should show the full classes. It looks like you've got the infamous circular-reference error in JSON serialization.  It's easy to find how to fix this.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you. Solved it. Had to install NewtonsoftJson package and inject it the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the Lambda Expression. As of now you can not filter an Include statement. If you want a filtered result, you shall have to fetch them all to memory and filter them. In your case, you don't even need to filter the include part. Only including the navigation property will just work fine. Assuming the parameter is used to filter the consignment table.

```
    // GET: api/Consignments
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Consignment>> GetConsignment(Guid id)
    {
        var consignment = await _context.Consignment.Where(x=>x.Id == id)
                .Include(conline => conline.ConsignmentLine)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        return consignment;
    }
```

The above code will simply give you the records from `Consignmet` Table, and Its `ConsignmentLine`. Try and let me know if this works.

However, this might throw an `JSON.NET Error Self-referencing loop detected for type error`. If you are getting this error, then you can resolve the same using the following method.

**If you are using AspNet Core**, add the followings to the `ConfigureServices()` method.

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(
        options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    );
```

> Happy Coding.<3

Comment: can you please look at my question again. I have provided my ConsignmentLine  and Legging class too. 

The updated controller code is throwing me a  -JSON object exception.

Comment: Then this might be an issue with the JSON serializer. I have updated the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Yes, it was an issue with JSON serializer. Fixed it yesterday. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As comment said, you can't use any filtering in Include.

And GetConsignment method returns the type of Consignment, not the list set, therefore, you need to convert the consignment variable through `FirstOrDefaultAsync` or `SingleOrDefaultAsync`.

Try changing the code to the following :

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Consignment>>  GetConsignment(Guid id)       
{ 
        var consignment = await _context.Consignment.Where(x=>x.Id == id)
        .Include(conline => conline.ConsignmentLine)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return consignment; 
}
```

And here is my ConsignmentLine.cs :

```
 public class ConsignmentLine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

To load related data in linq, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

Comment: I have updated my question can you have a look at it again?

Comment: @ShakerKamal, I have used your model of ConsignmentLine,and the result it's the same as my demo, you can use my code to test, don't use where in Include. and use FirstOrDefaultAsync.